#  ide and pci bus commands

Tags: command-line

Is the ide interface also a bus? Is there a command like lspci or lsusb, to find out what devices are on the ide bus? Sources seem to contradict eachother. I'm asking this question here because of the need to know how to explore the bus in linux, but I would also like to make sure I understand what it is to begin with. Would that there is command like lssata as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to wikipedia, IDE is a bus: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA

As far as I know there's no tool to scan the IDE bus apart from letting the kernel do it. I think it might interfere with regular I/O.